# button command doesnt callback function

Tags: python, tkinter

Widget is displayed but button does nothing. Why? The code isn't right? In some IDEs y simply can't import tkinter

```
# import tkinter
from tkinter import *

# ven Widget
ven = Tk()
boton = Button(ven,  text="hola",  command="cerrar")
boton.pack()

# function
def cerrar():
    ven.destroy

ven.mainloop()
```

Comment: doesn't work even with the proper identation in the "cerrar" function. Copy mistake

Comment: `command=cerrar` without the double quote. And move your function `cerrar` above the button creation.

Answer (score 1):

What @HenryYik said in the comments:

> command=cerrar without the double quote. And move your function cerrar
>   above the button creation

```
import tkinter as tk


def cerrar():
    ven.destroy()   # add parens to call the method 


ven = tk.Tk()
boton = tk.Button(ven, text="hola", command=cerrar)
boton.pack()

ven.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything just fine. The problem was the import method. from tkinter import * didn't work and i don't understand why. But thanks